# CanDeactivate does not work in Angular2

Tags: typescript, angular

I use Angular 2 RC.4 and new Router (3.0.0-alpha.8).
`router-deprecated` provides OnDeactivate Interface, a function implements it is called when the component was deactivated. But new router does not support OnDeactivate Interface but we can use CanDeactivate Interface instead.

I want to make a component to output messages when users move to other pages (deactivate current component), but CanDeactivate does not work.

```
// app.components.ts
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
...
export class AppComponent implements CanDeactivate<any> {
  canDeactivate(): boolean {
    // When users move to other pages, this component should output "foo" message.
    // But it does not work...
    console.log('foo');
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: new Router is in beta now i.e. version 3.0.0-beta.1 Refer sample application here - https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/router/ts/plnkr.html.

Comment: I just upgraded to 3.0.0-beta.1 and refer "app/crisis-center/crisis-detail.component.ts" of the URL, but it doesn't work yet...